# Django - Creating objects with m2m relationship while saving form

Tags: django, modelform

My models are as follows:

```
class Photo(models.Model):

  objects = PhotoManager()

  date = models.DateField()
  credit = models.CharField(max_length=60)
  sites = models.ManyToManyField(Site)
  tags = models.ManyToManyField('PhotoTag', related_name='photos')
  caption = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
  photo_src = models.ImageField()


class PhotoTag(models.Model):

  slug = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Relevant line from my PhotoUploadForm

```
tags = forms.CharField(max_length=250)
```

What I'm trying to do is take the tags field, split by comma it into a list, get_or_create them as PhotoTag objects, then add those to the Photo object in the current form. Probably in the form save method, right? Something like this (this is not working):

```
def save(self, commit=True):

    photo = super(PhotoUploadForm, self).save(commit=False)

    tags = [x.strip() for x in photo.tags.split(',')]

    photo.tags = []

    for tag in tags:
      tag = PhotoTag.objects.get_or_create(slugify(tag))
      photo.tags.append(tag)

    if commit:
      photo.save()

    return photo
```

I think I have the principle correct, but the execution is not. I would appreciate guidance and learning the correct way to think about this!

Updated with error traceback:

```
Traceback:
File "/vagrant/default_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/vagrant/default_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/vagrant/projects/bluehorse/bluehorse/apps/photos/views.py" in create_form
  46.       photo = form.save(commit=False)
File "/vagrant/projects/bluehorse/bluehorse/apps/photos/forms.py" in save
  31.     tags = [x.strip() for x in photo.tags.split(',')]
File "/vagrant/default_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py" in __get__
  1175.             through=self.field.rel.through,
File "/vagrant/default_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py" in __init__
  831.                                  (instance, source_field_name))

Exception Type: ValueError at /admin/photos/create
Exception Value: "<Photo: Photo object>" needs to have a value for field "photo" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

Comment: can you post your error trace ?

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

I misread you question sorry. You have a few problems here. The first is this line

```
[x.strip() for x in photo.tags.split(',')]
```

`photo.tags` is actually a `ManyToMany` here as

```
photo = super(PhotoUploadForm, self).save(commit=False)
```

returns an unsaved `Photo` object. You might actually want to use

```
tags = [x.strip() for x in self.cleaned_data['tags'].split(',')]
```

because `self.clean_data` will contain the data in the form, and the `Photo` object won't have the data atatched until after you have called `save` on it.

You can't add `ManyToMany`'s until you have actually created the object in the database, because behind the scenes a `ManyToMany` table looks roughly like this:

```
class Photo_PhotoTag_M2M_table(models.Model):
    photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo)
    phototag = models.ForeignKey(PhotoTag)
```

In your `PhotoUploadForm.save` function, the `Photo` object actually gets created in the database when you do this line `photo.save()`. So you need to add your manytomany's after you have created to form.

(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how this works with forms but when overriding the save method for models, you can't access m2m fields directly, you must use the [m2m_changed signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/signals/#m2m-changed).

I bet here the same is happening because the traceback is similar.